# Force user authentication when use cocoapod and limit a username per one install

Tags: ios, ssh, dependency-injection, cocoapods

I have a private cocoapod, which I am planning to provide to my clients so that they can use their project for a specific work. That library is paid one so what I want, I want to restrict the users to install the cocoapod with username/password which in some way, I can integrate in my BitBucket repos, so when the request comes from that SSH key or like that, it start the install.

I also want to restrict the no of install per user name like if I am restricting a pod to be installed twice then on third time, it should not got installed.

How to achieve the above two options? We can restrict as per the bundle identifier/ SSH key of the system etc.

Comment: I don't think that this approach will work.  Once they have the code they can use it as they will either have the source code or the compiled framework, depending on what you are providing and integrating this into any number of projects on any number of computers. You can only really address this through contracts and law.

Comment: If you are only providing a compiled framework then you could perhaps provide a license file that they would need to include in the app bundle.  This file would be digitally signed using a private key and the signed data would include their app's bundle ID. Then, at runtime, you can read this file, decrypt the information using the corresponding public key embedded in your framework and verify the bundle ID.

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks for sharing such a beautiful concept.  Cant we assign a SSH key in our repos and when some one type "pod install", we will check if that particular request is from that particular SSH key...

Comment: Well, you can use an SSH key to give them read permission but once they have the code they can do what they want with it.

Comment: but again, they would get the .h files as I am sending only frameworks

Comment: Yes, but they could use it in as many projects as they wanted

Comment: hmmm thats true....that signed file concept will work then perfectly!!!

Comment: @Paulw11..can you let me know how to create that type of files with bundle info in it and how to read it as I am new to this!!! any example would be acceptable.